# Android - Reading a text file and displaying all items or selected items (using query)

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, text

I would like to create a programm that reads a plain text file then either lists all the items in the text file or lists items depending on what the user types in and which button is pressed. I haven't been able to run it yet, as there are a number of errors. I have attempted to use the developer.android.com website, youTube and google to find solutions but the more I adjust the code the worse the problems seem to get. Below are the pieces of code I have come up with so far, including the text file, the manifest and fragment files.

info_sample.txt

```
Equipment Type  Equipment ID    Location    Status      Time
Infusion Pump   1234              2          On         12:00
Hoist           3645              1          Off        13:00
Bed             2563              3          Occupied   14:00
```

fragment_cemmain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="clinical.equipment.monitor.CEMMainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/equiptype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/equiptype" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/equiptypetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/equiptype"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/equipid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/equiptypetext"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="@string/equipid" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/equipidtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/equipid"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/findequip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/equipidtext"
    android:text="@string/findequip" 
    android:onClick="findequip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/listallequip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/findequip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/findequip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/findequip"
    android:text="@string/listallequip"
    android:onClick="listallequip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/refreshall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:onClick="refreshall"
    android:text="@string/refresh" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cleartext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/findequip"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:onClick="cleartext"
    android:text="@string/cleartext" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CEMMainActivity.java

```
package clinical.equipment.monitor;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class CEMMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public class ListViewLoader extends ListActivity
implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

// These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve
static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID,
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};

// This is the select criteria
static final String SELECTION = "((" + 
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cemmain);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {// action if app does not start up correctly
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new       PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    // Clears all text in EditText fields

    Button clearalltext  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cleartext); 
    clearalltext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View c) {           
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.cleartext);
        clearText(group);       

        for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        View view = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText)view).setText("");
        }

        if(view instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() > 0))
            clearText((ViewGroup)group);

    }
        }
    });

//Action once Find button is clicked

    Button findequip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.findequip);
    findequip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View f) {    

        private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

            if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
                Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);
                //process Cursor and display results
            }
        }
                    }
    }
    });


 // ignores the text fields and lists all equipment in virtual table        

        Button listalldatabase  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.listallequip); 
        listalldatabase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){// may need correction
        public void onClick(View l) {               
                //meant to call DatabaseOpenHelper class

            }               

        } );


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cemmain, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cemmain,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="clinical.equipment.monitor"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="clinical.equipment.monitor.CEMMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

DatabaseOpenHelper.java

```
package clinical.equipment.monitor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "ListAllEquipment";

//The columns to be included in table
public static final String COL_TYPE = "EQUIPMENT TYPE";
public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
public static final String COL_LOCATION = "LOCATION";
public static final String COL_STATUS = "STATUS";
public static final String COL_TIME = "TIME";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EQUIPMENT LIST";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTS";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final DatabaseOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void Listalldatabase (Context context) {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);        


private static class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final Context mHelperContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                " USING fts3 (" +
                COL_TYPE + ", " +
                COL_ID + ", " + COL_LOCATION + ", " + COL_STATUS +", " + COL_TIME + ")";

    DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mHelperContext = context;
    }

            // populate the virtual table

        private void loadEquipmentList() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadType();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    private void loadType() throws IOException {
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.info_sample);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                if (strings.length < 5) continue;
                long list = addItem(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim(), strings[3].trim(), strings[4].trim());
                if (list < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }


    public long addItem (String type; String id; String location; String status; String time); {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(COL_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(COL_ID, id);
        initialValues.put(COL_LOCATION, location);
        initialValues.put(COL_STATUS, status);
        initialValues.put(COL_TIME, time);

        return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    }

    @Override                
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase list) {
            SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = list;
            mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            loadEquipmentList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

SearchForEquip.java

```
package clinical.equipment.monitor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.text.*;
import android.util.Log;

 public class SearchForEquip { 

String equiptypetext,equipidtext, input1, input2;

private boolean readytofind() {
    String input1 = equiptypetext.toString();
    String input2 = equipidtext.toString();

    if ((input1 != null) && (input2 != null))
    { return ((input1 != null) &&( input2 != null));
            }
    else if ((input1 == null) && (input2 != null))
    { return (input2 != null);
    }
    else if ((input1 != null) && (input2 == null)) {
        return (input1 != null);
    }
    else { return false;}
            }

public class DatabaseOpen {

    private static final String TAG = "FindEquipment";

    //The columns to be included in table
    public static final String COL_TYPE = "EQUIPMENT TYPE";
    public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COL_LOCATION = "LOCATION";
    public static final String COL_STATUS = "STATUS";
    public static final String COL_TIME = "TIME";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EQUIPMENT FOUND";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTS";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final static DatabaseOpen mDatabaseOpen;

        public DatabaseOpen(Context item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        public void DatabaseTable(Context item) {
        mDatabaseOpen = new DatabaseOpen(item);
}

    private static class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase mSearch;

        private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                    " USING fts3 (" +
                    COL_TYPE + ", " +
                    COL_ID + ", " + COL_LOCATION + ", " + COL_STATUS +", " + COL_TIME + ")";
        private static final Context mHelper = null;

        DatabaseOpen(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mHelper = item;
        }

        //here the code should compare the typed text to the text in the text file and return a match
        public Cursor getMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
            String selection1 = COL_TYPE + " MATCH ?";
            String selection2 = COL_ID + "MATCH ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

            return query(selection1, selection2, selectionArgs, columns);
        }

        private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
            SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);

            Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpen.getReadableDatabase(),
                    columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

            if (cursor == null) {
                return null;
            } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                cursor.close();
                return null;
            }
            return cursor;
        }

 // populate the virtual table

        private void loadSearchList() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadType();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

private void loadEquip() throws IOException {
    final Resources equip = mHelper.getResources();
    InputStream inputStream = equip.openRawResource(R.raw.info_sample);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
            if (strings.length < 5) continue;
            long list = addItem(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim(), strings[3].trim(), strings[4].trim());
            if (list < 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
            }
        }
    } finally { reader.close();}


    public long addItem (String type, String id, String location, String status, String time) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(COL_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(COL_ID, id);
        initialValues.put(COL_LOCATION, location);
        initialValues.put(COL_STATUS, status);
        initialValues.put(COL_TIME, time);

        return mSearch.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Extensive code of whole projects requires a lot of time to review, advisable is to post simple concise snippets of code, related to the problem area. One problem at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will repost my questions.